# Cannot get jQuery Lightbox working on Joomla

Tags: joomla, mootools, lightbox

I have followed [these instructions](http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery_lightbox_bal/demo/) at Balupton to the word but I cannot seem to get this lightbox working. I managed to get this working on another Mambo project last year but I cannot get this working on Joomla and I was wondering if it could be that there is a clash between Moo Tools and jQuery. Although this should not be the case because I have used the JT slideshow plugin without any problems!

Any advice on this? I cannot put up a link at this stage sorry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using jquery.noconflict() to prevent it the namespace clashing?

Comment: No not yet. How do I use that Jeepstone?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Just put the noconflict code at the start of your jquery stuff. You qill need to update your jquery to use whatever prefix you choose.

Comment: Thanks Jeepstone! Much appreciated!